# React Native - Location Search Bar

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, geolocation

I am currently creating a mobile application in React Native using Expo that has some features that are location specific. Meaning, it would require users to enter in their location to use some features. This location will be stored locally in the device and the only piece of information that will be exported is the post/zip code for analytical reasons, so security is not an issue.

What are some resources that I can use to implement such feature and/or how can I go around implementing such a feature?
I am still a beginner in React Native so some guidance will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require your users to access their location. You can try : "requestForegroundPermissionsAsync" and get the current location: "getCurrentPositionAsync"